# Which key store should I read to see the installed certificates

Tags: android, security, encryption, certificate, public-key-encryption

Am installing certificate(.pk12) in my galaxy s2 from settings.After installing it shows toast " installed ". After that in my code am opening "/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks" key store and from it i can see number of aliases in keystore is 44 .Regardless of how many number of certificates I install the aliases count does not change. I doubt whether the installed certificates go to this key store itself.How do I confirm it?

Which key store should I read to see the installed certificates.

Comment: I don't know Adroid, so I cannot post this as an answer, but I do know that PKCS#12 is a keystore all in itself. Normally the alias of the certificate/private key in it is a counter value, e.g. "1".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you're trying to do, unless you root the phone. Importing certificates using the standard interface (settings) only allows you to import certificates for VPN or Wi-Fi connections. To actually modify the system store (cacerts.bks), a system update from the manufacturer must be made to implement the new cacerts.bks file.

Details here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11231#c25

If you root the phone, you can directly modify cacerts.bks, but stock Android does not permit this operation.